# Repeat code for multiple rows

Tags: excel, vba, loops, repeat

I have VBA code below that works great for one row. I need this to loop for 100 rows and do the same job for each row. Can someone help me do this?

```
Sub IsEmptyRange()

Dim cell As Range

Dim bIsEmpty As Boolean

bIsEmpty = False

For Each cell In Range("A1:H1")

    If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then

        bIsEmpty = True

        Exit For

    End If

Next cell

If bIsEmpty = True Then

    '**PLACE CODE HERE**

    [I1].Value = "Empty Cells"

Else

    '**PLACE CODE HERE**

    [I1].Value = "Complete"

End If

End Sub
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Does this need to be VBA at all?  It looks like you can use this formula in cell i1 and copy down: `=IF(COUNTBLANK(A1:H1)>0,"Empty Cells","Complete")`

Comment: wow, thank you so much! That's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this need to be VBA at all? It looks like you can use this formula in cell i1 and copy down: `=IF(COUNTBLANK(A1:H1)>0,"Empty Cells","Complete")`

If it absolutely must be VBA, then this will work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lLastRow As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next
    lLastRow = ws.Range("A:H").Find("*", ws.Range("A1"), xlValues, xlPart, , xlPrevious).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
    If lLastRow = 0 Then Exit Sub   'No data

    With ws.Range("I1:I" & lLastRow)
        .Formula = "=IF(COUNTBLANK(A" & .Row & ":H" & .Row & ")>0,""Empty Cells"",""Complete"")"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try implementing this?

```
* = things added/changed (remove when you put in VBA)

*Dim lRow as Integer
*Dim i as Integer

*lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

*For i = 1 to lRow
For Each cell In Range("A" & i & ":H" & i)

If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then

    bIsEmpty = True

    Exit For

End If

Next cell

If bIsEmpty = True Then

'**PLACE CODE HERE**

*[I & i].Value = "Empty Cells"

Else

'**PLACE CODE HERE**

*[I & i].Value = "Complete"

End If
*Next i
```

Comment: thanks so much for responding! When I made your additions, it still only runs for one row.....

Comment: @ForestWagner Hmm gotcha...I updated the code a little, did you have the [I & i] in your code?

Comment: I added that, I'm getting an run time error 424 object required